# remove the "\n" from string

Tags: c, string

I'm learning C recently and I didn't learn about pointers so still not allowed to use it.

**Note:** i'm not allowed to use it or any function from string.h library.

I wrote a function that removes the "\n" from a string.

when I run my program appears to me:

main.c:20:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
main.c:80:39: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

**This is my function:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRING_SIZE 100

void replace(char str[]){
    int i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if(str[i]=="\n"){
            str[i]='\0';
        }
    }
}

int my_strlen(char s[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        i++;

    }
    return i;

}

int remover(char s1[], char s2[], char s3[]) //removes the sustring s2 from string s1 and saved it to s3
{
    int i = 0, j, t = 0, found;

    while (s1[i])
    {
        found = 1;//Initilize found to true
        for (j = 0; s2[j] != 0; j++) {
            if (s1[i + j] != s2[j])
                found = 0;//Set not found
        }
        if (found == 0) {
            s3[t] = s1[i];// if not found add char to s3.
            t++;
        }
        else {
            i = i + my_strlen(s2) - 1;//if found skip
        }
        i++;
    }
    s3[t] = 0;
    if (my_strlen(s1) > my_strlen(s3)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}



int main() {
    char result_string[STRING_SIZE+1], MainString[STRING_SIZE+1], PatternString[STRING_SIZE+1];

    printf("Please enter the main string..\n");
    fgets(MainString, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);
    replace(MainString);

    printf("Please enter the pattern string to find..\n");
    fgets(PatternString, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);
    replace(PatternString);

    int is_stripped = remover(MainString, PatternString, result_string);
    printf("> ");
    printf(is_stripped ? result_string : "Cannot find the pattern in the string!");
    return 0;
}
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you haven't shown us all your code. Line 27 is probably `return helper;` (it would have been helpful to say so), but we can't see line 84. Please read this: [mre]

Comment: @KeithThompson i edited it

Comment: @Yasmina There are very few comments. Without knowing what `remover` is supposed to do, how can we tell if it does it right? Without knowing what its return value means, how can we know if it's correct?

Comment: After `fgets()`, one can use `MainString[strcspn(MainString, "\n")] = '\0';` to remove the potential `'\n'`.

Comment: it removes the sustring s2 from string s1 and saved it to s3 @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i'm not allowed to use it or any function from  <string.h> library.

Comment: `for(i=0; str[i] != 0; ++i) { if (str[i] == '\n') { str[i]=0; break; } }`  (untested)

Comment: `str[i] == "\n"` is always false. You are comparing a character with a string.

Comment: @Yasmina Such restrictions like "i'm not allowed to use it or any function from <string.h>" belong in the original post.  Not appended in comments,else your post is a moving target.

Comment: @3limin4t0r `str[i] == "\n"` is neither true nor false. It's a constraint violation. If a compiler lets it go with a warning, its behavior is undefined. (The most likely behavior is yielding false, but don't count on that.)

Comment: `while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if(str[i]=="\n"){
            str[i]='\0';
        }
    }` is an infinite loop as `i` is constant.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems:

1. Your function returns a `char`, which is a single character.
2. A C-style string has to have a terminating zero byte. You don't put one on `helper`. So even if you could return it properly, the code that got it would have no way to know how long the string was.
3. You allocate `helper` on the stack in `replace`, so `helper` stops existing when you return. So where will the returned string be stored?

Comment: The right way depends on how you want to call and use it. Do you want the function to allocate memory? Do you want the called to free it? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: ... or just replace the '\n' with '\0' and modify the string in place ... assuming this is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `'\n'` from the string, in place, modifying the original string.
For instance:

```
void remove_newline(char str[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; str[i] != 0; ++i) 
    { 
        if (str[i] == '\n') 
        { 
            str[i] = 0; 
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: still appears to me this: main.c:107:39: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]   ... what is that mean ?

Comment: neither the code you posted nor the code i posted has 107 lines. so i can't say.  but i'm guessing it's an incorrect call to printf